# How to deal with contexts in Spark/Scala when using map()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm not very familiar with Scala, neither with Spark, and I'm trying to develop a basic test to understand how DataFrames actually work. My objective is to update my myDF based on values of some registries of another table.

Well, on the one hand, I have my App:

```
object TestApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val conf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local[*]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    implicit val hiveContext : SQLContext = new HiveContext(sc)
    val test: Test = new Test()
    test.test
  }
}
```

On the other hand, I have my Test class :

```
class Test(implicit sqlContext: SQLContext) extends Serializable {

  val hiveContext: SQLContext = sqlContext
  import hiveContext.implicits._

  def test(): Unit = {
    val myDF = hiveContext.read.table("myDB.Customers").sort($"cod_a", $"start_date".desc)
    myDF.map(myMap).take(1)
  }
  def myMap(row: Row): Row = {
    def _myMap: (String, String) = {
      val investmentDF: DataFrame = hiveContext.read.table("myDB.Investment")
      var target: (String, String) = casoX(investmentDF, row.getAs[String]("cod_a"), row.getAs[String]("cod_p"))
      target
    }
    def casoX(df: DataFrame, codA: String, codP: String)(implicit hiveContext: SQLContext): (String, String) = {
      var rows: Array[Row] = null
      if (codP != null) {
        println(df)
        rows = df.filter($"cod_a" === codA && $"cod_p" === codP).orderBy($"sales".desc).select($"cod_t", $"nom_t").collect
      } else {
        rows = df.filter($"cod_a" === codA).orderBy($"sales".desc).select($"cod_t", $"nom_t").collect
      }
      if (rows.length > 0) (row(0).asInstanceOf[String], row(1).asInstanceOf[String]) else null
    }
    val target: (String, String) = _myMap
    Row(row(0), row(1), row(2), row(3), row(4), row(5), row(6), target._1, target._2, row(9))
  }
}
```

`Well, when I execute it, I have a NullPointerException on the instruction val investmentDF: DataFrame = hiveContext.read.table("myDB.Investment")`, and more precisely `hiveContext.read`

If I analyze hiveContext in the "test" function, I can access to its SparkContext, and I can load my DF without any problem.
Nevertheless if I analyze my hiveContext object just before getting the NullPointerException, its sparkContext is null, and I suppose due to sparkContext is not Serializable (and as I am in a map function, I'm loosing part of my hiveContext object, am I right?)

Anyway, I don't know what's wrong exactly with my code, and how should I alter it to get my investmentDF without any NullPointerException?

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot nest distributed operations. Just use `join`.

Comment: Right... you were right, it didn't make sense what I was trying to do, I finally understood why :) I implemented it using multiple joins and it's working fine! Thanks @zero323!!